# How can I remove class dynamically before adding same kind of class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on this simple [app](https://battery-info.netlify.app) that shows the current battery status of your device.

The problem that I am facing is that I want to change the colour of the progress bar dynamically. So I made this function:

```
function changeBatteryColor(value) {
  let className, oldClassName;
  if (value >= 75 && value <= 100) className = "bg-success";
  else if (value >= 50 && value <= 75) className = "bg-info";
  else if (value >= 25 && value <= 50) className = "bg-warning";
  else if (value >= 0 && value <= 25) className = "bg-danger";
  return className;
}
```

I am calling this function: `progressBar.classList.add(changeBatteryColor(battery.level * 100));`
So the class gets added to the progress bar. But the older class is not removed. Is there a way I can remove the older class?

I will add the screenshot soon

Comment: Store the current class name in an outer scope variable, and use that variable to [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) the class in the function.

Comment: @Teemu but the class changes as per the condition given. So how can I detect which is the current class? BTW, it has other classes too. So it is hard to get the class for the background.

Comment: ?? You're explicitly assigning the class to a variable, what more detecting you need? For the first call you already know the default class given to the element.

Comment: The default class that I have given is "progress-bar progress-bar-striped". And I add that new class. But the problem is that I can't get the reference to the old class when another class is added and both of the classes stay there.

Comment: @Teemu Do you mean this? "const className = changeBatteryColor(battery.level * 100);" //global var
"progressBar.classList.remove(className);"
Sorry to ping you BTW.

Comment: Why can't you get a reference? Again: You're defining a new class name, just store it as an "oldClassName" before leaving `changeBatteryColor` function, and at the beginning of the function, just remove the class `oldClassName` contains. If there's no default class name to change, that's not a problem, `remove` can handle a dummy string too. You don't have to wait your battery to go low, you can make a [test](https://jsfiddle.net/n2y79e81/) ... Pinging is OK, if you've something to ask.

Comment: Oh great. Thanks for the help both of you. Helped me a lot. Solved the issue.

Comment: The majority of phones come with a battery status indicator near the top. Not many need an app for this.

Comment: @QuentinUK Yeah but I made it for practice. And also for my channel so that I can use a web framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, this solves your problem.

```
let oldClassName;

function changeBatteryColor(value) {
  if(oldClassName) {
      progressBar.classList.remove(oldClassName) // removing the prev classname 
  }
  let className ;
  if (value >= 75 && value <= 100) className = "bg-success";
  else if (value >= 50 && value <= 75) className = "bg-info";
  else if (value >= 25 && value <= 50) className = "bg-warning";
  else if (value >= 0 && value <= 25) className = "bg-danger";
  oldClassName = className; // asigning the current classname to remove this classname next fun call
  return className;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need to check if this works. My battery is 80% r8 now. Let's see if it changes the color when it hits 74%

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: Are you from India? I am.

Comment: from Nepal. near near :)